# Magento 2 Fedex Shipping Method Showing 0$ a lot of times

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping-methods, fedex

I have integrated FEDEX Shipping in my Magento 2 Store. It was working till now. But suddenly from today It's showing a lot of 0$ options without any method name. Can anyone help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know your question was asked a while ago, but I got the same issue yesterday and I've fixed it today... so in order to leave no one behind here's what I did:

I've first check if the problem was still there when using the Magento Blank template, and it was. That said, I've deleted Magento from my vendor and reloaded it.

Problem solved! Hope this helps!